# User Cross Domain Authentication Explanation

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, trust-relationship

We have a domain in the 2008 R2 domain functional level....all DC's are 2008 R2. We also have a Windows 2000 domain. The domains are not trusted.

From any server in Domain A (Windows 2008 R2), I can map a drive to a server in Domain B (Windows 2000). It prompts me for credentials for Domain B which I type and it works.

I am confused on the domains see each other if they are not trusted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Domain trust or lack of has nothing in common with ability to map network drive. Domain trust allows you to use (export, permission to share) credentials (password database) from one domain in another (one-way trust), it allows you to share credentials between AD domains too. (two-way trust)

Comment: So Connect As has nothing to do with a domain trust. As long as the servers are accessible over the network. Thank you.

Comment: That is correct.